# Can anyone explain how this code snippet outputs 6561

Tags: php

**Can anyone explain how this code snippet outputs 6561**
code:

```
function f(& $x, $c)
{
    $c = $c - 1;

    if ($c == 0)
    {
        return 1; 
    }

    $x = $x + 1;
    return f($x,$c) * $x;
}
$p = 5;
$a = f($p, 5);
print_r($a);
```

Thanks

Comment: The best way to learn this is to pretend to be the computer executing the statements. Write the values of the variables down on a piece of paper, updating them as you go.

Comment: Or setup a PHP debugger and watch it run line by line

Comment: Just remember that each recursive call has its own variables, except that the reference variables are shared.

Comment: I don't think the result of this is well defined, though. `f($x, $c)` modifies `$x` in the function call because of the reference parameter. But PHP doesn't specify the order of evaluation of the sub-expressions, so we don't know whether `* $x` uses the original or updated value of `$x`.

Comment: I am not getting the vale of x in the line return `f($x,$c) * $x;`. and how it outputs 6561

Answer (score 1):

Using echoes and a variable assignment can help. If I change your code to this:

```
function f(& $x, $c)
{
    echo "X is $x, C is $c \n";
    $c = $c - 1;
    echo "C is now $c\n";

    if ($c == 0)
    {
        return 1; 
    }

    $x = $x + 1;
    echo "X is now $x\n";
    $y =  f($x,$c) * $x;
    echo "Multiplying the result by $x, Y is $y\n";
    return $y;
}
$p = 5;
$a = f($p, 5);
print_r($a);
```

You get the following output:

```
X is 5, C is 5 
C is now 4
X is now 6
X is 6, C is 4 
C is now 3
X is now 7
X is 7, C is 3 
C is now 2
X is now 8
X is 8, C is 2 
C is now 1
X is now 9
X is 9, C is 1 
C is now 0
Multiplying the result by 9, Y is 9
Multiplying the result by 9, Y is 81
Multiplying the result by 9, Y is 729
Multiplying the result by 9, Y is 6561
6561
```

You're modifying the pointer of $x, not just a variable, so it changes to 9 all the way through before it hits all of the multiplications on the return.